# Are rational varieties symplectically rationally connected?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, toric-varieties, gromov-witten-theory

Was it proven already that smooth rational complex projecitve varieties are symplectically rationally connected? I.e. some GW invariant with two point insertions is non zero. What about smooth toric varieties?

Comment: That is an open conjecture.  The major progress is by Zhiyu Tian, who proved the conjecture in dimension 3. "Symplectic geometry of rationally connected threefolds."  Duke Math. J. 161, no. 5 (2012), pp. 803--843.

Comment: . . . I missed the word "rational" in the question.  I doubt that there is much more known in the rational case than in the general rationally connected case.  However, in the toric case, it is likely that more can be proved.

Comment: Thanks Jason! The abstract of this paper on arxiv seem to claim a bit less than what you say (I imaging the final version proves a stronger result)

Comment: I did not read carefully enough your post.  I agree that it is not yet known whether there is a nonzero, two-point, genus $0$ Gromov-Witten invariant.  Tian did prove symplectic invariance of rational connectedness.

Comment: Here is an idea in the toric case.  This idea is close to the proof by Yifei Chen and Shokurov of "strong rational connectedness" for toric varieties.  The "universal torsor" over a smooth, projective toric variety is an open subset of an affine space, and the toric variety is a GIT quotient of the universal torsor.  For a general pair of points in that open subset, there is a unique line in the affine space connecting the points.  The (rational) image is a rational curve in the toric variety.  Is the corresponding $2$-point Gromov-Witten invariant of this curve class equal to $1$?

Comment: @JasonStarr There is no hope doing this using just the classes of the two points and no other classes. On $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$, the space of rational $(a,b)$ curves through two general points is $2a+2b-3$-dimensional if $a>0,b>0$ and is empty otherwise, so it is never zero-dimensional. I think your construction produces a $(1,1)$ curve and thus a one-dimensional moduli space.

Comment: @JasonStarr I guess the problem here is that given two general points in the toric variety, there are multiple ways to lift them to the universal cover and thus multiple straight lines between them, which do not in general map to the same rational curve in the toric variety.